# angularjs + ui.router: different behavior between directive controller and link functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive `external-link` causing the link in which it is placed to open the url in a separate window instead of the current

```
<a app-external-link href="http://example.com">Example</a>
```

It is like `target="_blank"` but with the ability to track when users click on it

For the sake of the example I removed the tracking feature so it only has to behave like the `target=_blank` attribute

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('appExternalLink', function ($window) {
  var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $window.open(attrs.href, '_blank');
    });
  };

  return {
    scope: true,
    link: link
  };
});
```

This implementation works as expected. What surprised me is that in my
first approach I was using directive's controller:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('appExternalLink', function ($window) {
  var controller = function ($element, $attrs) {
    $element.on('click', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $window.open($attrs.href, '_blank');
    });
  };

  return {
    scope: true,
    controller: controller
  };
});
```

I don't understand why (hence this question) in the directive controller
example the link successfully opens in a new window but **it also changes
the current view to the new url**

It is as if `event.preventDefault()` does nothing in this case

Any ideas on why this happens?

**Update:**

The issue only happens when the directive is used with `ui-sref`

```
<a app-external-link ui-sref="foo">Example</a>
```

[Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vgvCIa)

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: I was wondering because I couldn't reproduce your issue without removing `preventDefault`. Also, if you leave `href` empty and just pass the url into your directive from a different attribute, you won't even have to use `preventDefault` because [angular handles this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/a), since it 

"Modifies the default behavior of the html A tag so that the default action is prevented when the href attribute is empty"

Comment: @CShark I'm using version 1.5.3 I can't reproduce it in a plunk neither but I do in my project. So I need a closer look to the problem. The alternative attribute approach is a good idea too. thx!

Comment: Ok, I keep researching... I think it is related to having `ui-sref` in the same element. Plunk comming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 potential solutions.

1. Use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in combination with `event.preventDefault()` for the click handler in the `controller` to stop the current page url from changing as well.

   **Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/6Qi8NcWMmOvC4R3ZAqsf?p=info
2. `ui-sref` does work with `target="_blank"` already, so have your directive just add that attribute to the element and then do whatever you want to do in your click handler without even having to worry about dealing with the event or using `window.open`.

   ```
   element.attr('target', '_blank');
   element.on('click', function (event) {
       //can track clicks or do whatever you want here
       console.log(attrs.href + ' opened in new tab.');
   });
   ```

   **Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/brvftLiqXLznS6IWNmVA?p=info

I prefer **2** because of the reasons I listed and because it's less code and it lets `angular` and `ui-router` do their work separately from what you are trying to do (rather than having to somewhat duplicate some logic). Also, I haven't really tested **1** all that much and it might impact other things that I haven't seen yet. It does appear to work though, if you would prefer to do it that way.